# Apple OS X Server (Xcode CI service) can't find provisioning profiles

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode5, code-signing, ios-provisioning, osx-server

I configured dedicated Mac mini with OS X Server for Continuous Integration with XCode5, added git repo and created bots. I am trying to integrate bot and get error

```
Specified PROVISIONING_PROFILE (29DAD4E2-6155-4395-AF33-2C872BC32504) not 
found and no CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY specified. Ignoring PROVISIONING_PROFILE 
for now. This will become an error in the future.
```

Server was added to Developer Team and I can see it in member center at special page "Servers". I think that server should retreive profiles from Developer Center for build bots, but it doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that problem resolved. I checked server logs (Xcode -> Service log) and find that device list and provisioning profiles are correct downloaded after relogin to team (saved to

```
/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/ProvisioningProfiles
```

(from comments)

> With the release of OS X Server 3.2.1, the provisioning profiles have been relocated to `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles`

with _teamserver owner). Server download only automatic generated profiles ("iOS Team Provisionong Profile: bundle id") and you should choose this profile in target settings and commit to your VCS.

Comment: Adding my development team to the XCode Service in the OSX server still isn't working... If I manually download my provisioning profiles and copy them into the directory you mention it does find them, but now can't find my certificates. Any ideas?

Comment: Found this awesome tutorial to get around some of the nastiness of setting up the XCode service: http://matt.vlasach.com/xcode-bots-hosted-git-repositories-and-automated-testflight-builds/

Comment: With the release of OS X Server 3.2.1, the provisioning profiles have been relocated to /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles

Answer (score 0):

Adding Developer Account in Xcode->Preferences worked for me.

My environment:

- Xcode 7.* and Server 5.
- I have added my server to developer team