# Xcode continuous integration provisioning profile error

Tags: xcode5

I am trying to setup continuous integration in Xcode 5 on Mavericks. If I have a bot do a new clean project build, it completes with no errors. If I have the bot do the build on my actual project, I get the following error:

> No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a
>   provisioning profile with the UUID
>   “XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX”, however, no such provisioning
>   profile was found. CodeSign error: code signing is required for
>   product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'

If I pull latest source on the server machine and build/archive it on the server it works as expected. All expected certificates and public keys are included in keychain. I have tried to update all provisioning profile settings in the project and build target the scheme points at. Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this error?

EDIT:
After cracking open the project file and looking at the UUID, from what I can tell the UUID for the provisioning file it can't find does exist. Perhaps this is some kind of permission issue with the build not having access to the profile or keychain certificate?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally managed to make it work.

First of all, [I added my server to my developer team](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/200-Adopting_a_Continuous_Integration_Workflow/adopt_continuous_integration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH3-SW4) but I had the same error as you.

Then I copied my key from `user keychain` to `system keychain` as indicated [here](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2013/10/xcode-bots-common-problems-and-workarounds/) but it was still not enough.

And finally, I copied the provisioning profiles from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` to `/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` (in fact I copied all the MobileDevice directory because it didn't exist).

And now, I have a working continuous integration giving me an ipa which I can download on my Mac or install over the air on my devices.

I don't know why I had to do this, but I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: Didn't work here. But this did save us: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11167851/76522

Comment: @iDou Any explanation why does this copy (`cp -r ~/Library/MobileDevice/ /Library/MobileDevice/`) make the trick?

Comment: At least on my setup, the "proper" destination path seems to be `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles/` instead of `/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/`…

Comment: In Xcode 6 with Xcode Server 3.2.1 the paths probably changed as described by @KaelinColclasure in the previous comment. In the end I found out there is no need to copy anything. Just setup Xcode Server properly. Please check out my answer and let me know if that is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25993995/300694

Comment: This solution worked for me in Xcode 6, but I chose to symlink rather than copy the folder: `sudo ln -s ~/Library/MobileDevice/ /Library/MobileDevice`

Comment: should also add that this worked for me in OS Server 4.0.3 & Xcode 6

Comment: Just copying and pasting the certificate(with included private key) into the system keychain worked for me :)

Comment: You're a saint. I had been trying to figure this out for days. My /Library didn't even have a MobileDevice directory.

Comment: Had the same problem in OS X Server 5.1.7 with XCode 7.3.1. Changing nothing but simply running the integration again fixed it.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem since switching to Xcode 5. My solution was different.

Since the error message said "Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID xxxxxx", I checked the file containing my build setting (myproject.xcodeproj/projecjt.pbxproj).

There I found a line with exactly that UUID. After deleting the line (of course a made a backup of the file first), everything worked again.

Comment: Really weird but this fixed it for me too! I think its about NOT specifying an explicit UUID (which is liable to change as you add devices etc.) but instead using whatever developer or distribution profile is already installed.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. But I did not edit the .pbxproj file, but rather changed the settings in Xcode 5 by clicking on the project in Project Navigator and changing Build Settings > Code Signing > Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Worked for me! No matter what I selected in Xcode, it didn't obey. So I edit the .pbxproj file and it worked!

Comment: Same here, Xcode 5 would not delete the UUID without editing the project file.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I had the same issue and the problem was I had the certificates in my login keychain and the build script was looking in System keychain. I copied the certificate in system key chain also and now Xcode was able to use the provisioning profile for the build

Answer (score 3):

after searching how to solve this problem , after spending 1 whole day in front of my keyboard , looking through all pages and ideas how to solve this i actually found something interesting out.

Something came on my mind mentioned (edit YOU_APP.xcodeproj). So I SOLVED THIS:

1. Go to your project folder
2. Right click on **YOU_APP.xcodeproj** and choose **Show Package Contents**
3. Edit project.pbxproj with (for example TextMate2 or somethig like this)
4. NOW Attention. I found everything where this UUID (wrong UUID) will be displayed and just replaced with my i created and have been using for several time. I replaced 13 times.
5. done. Just compile and thats it.

You will not believe but it worked after spending a lot of time.  =)

Comment: This worked for me.  I recommend everyone try this simple solution before getting to far in.

Answer (score 1):

I kept searching the net for the past few weeks trying to establish Continuous Integration through Jenkins & when failed through OS X Server Bots, both failed with the same exact issue.

Copying the Provisioning Profiles from "**~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/**" to "**/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/**" was the only key.

Just two points to take care off :-

1-If you are using OS X Lion, take care that your **~/Library** folder will **not appear** in Finder as it is set as **invisible**; Please refer to http://www.macworld.com/article/1161156/view_library_folder_in_lion.html to see it.

2-Don't bring the provisioning profile on your own (e.g. download it from MemberCenter or so, ... ) just copy the profiles exiting in your ~/Library/...; their naming is different; they are all named by the UUID, e.g.3D19E524-9E2A-45C2-942C-F30AC3ACF0CC**.mobileprovision**

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and none of the above answers worked for me. I referenced [This blog](http://matt.vlasach.com/xcode-bots-hosted-git-repositories-and-automated-testflight-builds/) and copied my provisioning profiles from the ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ directory to the /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/ProvisioningProfiles directory and I still got the same error.

So I opened Xcode and synchronized my profiles with the provisioning portal. If you are unfamiliar, go to Preferences -> Accounts -> , highlight the developer team and click "View Details". Then highlight the distribution code signing identity in "Signing Identities" and click on the refresh button in the bottom left corner. I did this from the server, however, I'm sure you could refresh your provisioning profiles on your development mac and then copy them to the server.

This process refreshes the provisioning profiles in the ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ directory. I then reattempted the copy process to /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/ProvisioningProfiles from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ and the Xcode bot successfully found the provisioning profile during the next integration.

As a note, I tried signing out of the Xcode service's developer team and signing back in and that peculiarly did not work for me. Theoretically that should accomplish the same thing.

Like others have mentioned, I would copy all of the profiles rather than finding only the Ad Hoc profile you are looking for. The reason is that maybe, like in my case, the Xcode bot was attempting to archive with the development profile and "Development Profile" is much easier to debug than "4F96F173-7EBE-4892-B283-52489DE2F409".

If this still does not work, I suggest following the link above and go through the certificate process; you take the certificate from your developer computer and copy it into the system folder of the Keychain Access application on your server.

Just to add a note since this also gave me a big headache, the simulator for Xcode bots may be located at /var/_xcstest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/. That is where I found it on our server but I doubt it would be different for others. I had to find it because the Localizable.strings file was not being updated in the simulator and tests were failing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solution is way simpler than copying provisioning profiles around or the like. All you need to do is setup Xcode Server correctly.

I am using Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317) with Xcode Server 3.2.1 (13S5179). While I thought that Xcode Server would use the provisioning profiles from my Xcode installation, it does not. It has its own folder at `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles/`, whereas Xcode would use `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/`.

**So the solution is:**
Add your developer accounts to Xcode Server. It will then automatically download all necessary provisioning profiles automagically so your CI builds finally have access to the provisioning profiles. You add an account by clicking that `Edit...` button in the `Builds` section of Xcode Server as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I had set my Server up just as you describe, but still found it did not pick up new provisioning profiles added to the team. And re-adding the team did not seem to do the trick either… The only thing that got me further along was manually copying the files as described [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639398/xcode-continuous-integration-provisioning-profile-error/19647125?noredirect=1#comment40706242_19647125]

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Xcode Server. If I can't fix this on my side in the next couple of days I will file a radar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: I've added the provisioning profiles to /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/ProvisioningProfiles but got this error. The solution is to change permissions for the provisioning profiles, so everyone in the system can read them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the answers here before sitting back and thinking that it couldn't be this hard. Searched again and found this [Apple OS X Server (Xcode CI service) can't find provisioning profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568400/apple-os-x-server-xcode-ci-service-cant-find-provisioning-profiles)

I needed to use the correct team provisioning profiles. This page also links to a good tutorial as well.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the whole `~/Library/Developer/XCode` folder should fix the caching issue. Then the provisioning profiles located in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` should be found properly by xcode.

Answer (score 0):

@amrsd Thanks.  I see now that a lot of people are copying the profiles manually from their "Provisioning Profiles" folder in "~/Library/MobileDevice" with success (including myself).  If this is the route you're taking as well, quit copy+pasting and symlink it!

`$ sudo -i`

`# mkdir /Library/MobileDevice; ln -s /Users/myuser/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/ /Library/MobileDevice/` -- where **myuser** is your username.