# Build machine does not recognize a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm using a remote mac machine as a build machine,
I don't have root permissions on it.

I'm trying to use a provisioning profile by copying my file into the folder:  `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`
with it's UUID as the file name (and .mobileprovision as the extension)
When I run the build and specifying the UUID as the `PROVISIONING_PROFILE` parameter I get:

`Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “xxx”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.`

I saw a thread in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639398/xcode-continuous-integration-provisioning-profile-error/23224009#23224009) that solves it by copying to either `"/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"` or `/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/ProvisioningProfiles`
but since I don't have root access I can't do it.

I'm using xcode-5.0.2.

The build command I'm issuing is:
`xcodebuild -configuration Distribution SDKROOT=pathTo/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk SYMROOT=somePath DSTROOT=somePath INSTALL_PATH=somePath 'CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]=iPhone Distribution: someName' OTHER_CFLAGS=-DINHOUSE_DEPLOY=1 PROVISIONING_PROFILE=xxx`

Is there any known work around for it?
How can I get the xcodebuild tool to know about this profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open provisioning profile in text editor and find there `UUID` tag:

```
<key>UUID</key>
<string>1A85CBE4-6DBE-4414-B361-98B0B2C47E43</string>
```

Set `UUID` tag value for `PROVISIONING_PROFILE` parameter.
In my case it looks like:

```
PROVISIONING_PROFILE=1A85CBE4-6DBE-4414-B361-98B0B2C47E43
```

Comment: no good, I get: Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “/Users/name/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/xxx.mobileprovision”, however, no such provisioning profile was found. it seems like this parameter is for UUID.

Comment: @sagioto What tool are you using for project building?

Comment: Could you provide whole code line of xcodebuild call with all parameters?

Comment: @sagioto I've totally updated my answer due new information in your question. Please try it.

Comment: @sagioto Did you try to setup provisioning profile in target configuration by Xcode and remove parameter PROVISIONING_PROFILE from xcodebuild call at all?