# Why does `ionic run ios` error with "No matching provisioning profile found"?

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, command-line-interface, sudo

My goal is to run my Ionic app on my iPhone. 
I don't figure out what could be the reason explaining this exception:

```
    myIonicApp$ sudo ionic run ios

    Check dependencies

    === BUILD TARGET WealCome OF PROJECT WealCome WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

    Check dependencies
    Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “dabcc352-0b59-415a-bcd1-6f6ea1d1fbe6”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.
    CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
```

I have this build settings:

[image]

The organizer:

[image]

Comment: Linked to the question I aksed here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-run-the-command-ionic-run-ios/10006/1  perhaps presenting more information.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As Mik378 said on his comment the right destination path of the provisioning profiles seems to be /Library/MobileDevice so all you have to do is copy everything you need to that folder:

```
sudo cp -r ~/Library/MobileDevice/ /Library/MobileDevice/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try going into Xcode preferences, into Accounts and clicking the refresh button at the bottom left of the dialog.

Comment: I've just done it. Same issue.  Is it possible than having several generated developers certificates causes conflicts? Indeed, in the folder I had an increment like this:  iOS Development(3). I guess XCode is smart enough to detect the good one...

Comment: I found the trick ! Even if I don't figure out why until now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19647125/985949  The solution was to run the following command: `sudo cp -r ~/Library/MobileDevice/ /Library/MobileDevice/`