# cordova build ios Error with team profile

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to build an ipa file with cordova cli:

```
sudo cordova build ios --device --release
```

I build before `build.json`:

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "developmentTeam": "----XZ",
      "packageType": "development",
      "buildFlag": [
        "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
        "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
        "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
    },
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
      "developmentTeam": "----XZ",
      "packageType": "app-store",
      "buildFlag": [
        "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
        "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
        "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And I get error:

```
Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: No profile for team '----XZ' matching 'App Distribution' found:  Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '----XZ/App Distribution'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.0'
```

I opened the Xcode(in the first time, i'm working with PhpStorm) and the sign area looks like that:
[image]

I've re-created all the certificates and still get an error....
Help please :(  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've already found the answer. Here is the trick:

[Why does `ionic run ios` error with "No matching provisioning profile found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968329/why-does-ionic-run-ios-error-with-no-matching-provisioning-profile-found). You need to copy your the provisioning profiles from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` to `/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/`