# Error when building application using cordova

Tags: xcode, cordova

I am using cordova 6.5.0 and when I run "cordova build ios" the build failed with error "No profile for team **** matching ***** found"

but when I open the project in Xcode I am able to build and archive using the same provision profile

How do I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cordova build ios Error with team profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543494/cordova-build-ios-error-with-team-profile)

Answer (score 1):

1) Do you have any Embedded Frameworks in your project?

**Go to Build Phases > Under Embed Frameworks**

```
Tick the checkbox for Code Sign On Copy
```

And try to build again

2) Try to double check your certificate and your provisioning profile if it is selected correctly

Hope it helps!