# Xcode / Why do we need to copy ~/Library/MobileDevice/ to /Library/MobileDevice/?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

While running the command `cordova run ios`, or `ionic run ios`, I came across this error:

```
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “31e9e9bb-8da1-48c6-9256-ec365145a0ac”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
```

At first glance, I decided to refresh my provisioning profiles, ensuring that they were valid and reachable. 
However, same issue occurred.
I'm pointing out that running the app from Xcode directly worked/works great.

Until I ... came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22381797/985949), suggesting to run this command:

`cp -r ~/Library/MobileDevice/ /Library/MobileDevice/`

Tried it and...the whole works!

I found that **very...ugly and totally non-intuitive.**

May anyone explain the essence of this kind of copy?
Isn't Xcode smart enough to handle that automatically?

That works, indeed, but I never want to admit things I don't figure out ;)

I don't understand what I've done.

Comment: what you did its just copy a folder from your users library (~) to the general library.

Comment: Yes exactly, that was the trick. Nothing more.

Comment: so, whats the doubt?

Comment: Actually, I'd like to understand why is this copy absolutely necessary? Does Xcode search within `~/` and the command-line within `/`?

Comment: maybe the problem its Cordova and maybe there is a flag (or a config file) to change that behavior. Anyway, I think thats a desirable behavior: the dependencies should be common