# OSX Server 3.2.1 integration build timing out when building sources

Tags: xcode, osx-server

I have upgraded to OSX Server 3.2.1 and I am trying to get my bots to work again. I have one of my projects working, but when I have a workspace that tries to build I get stuck at the following message:

> Integrating (step 4 of 9)...
>
> Building sources Please wait...

This hanged for about 10 minutes and then fails with the following error:

> Bot Issue: error. Build Service Error. Issue: Terminated xcodebuild
>   since it produced no output for too long.

There aren't any other errors I see in the error logs. Does anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I have the same exact problem, it's suck in "Building Sources: Signing product". Any fix, yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of my issue was due to a bug in Xcode server 3.2.1. In the previous version, it read all of its signing certificates from the system keychain. As of 3.2.1, it has its own private hidden keychain. There are 2 workarounds for this:

1. Override the xcode keychain with your existing system keychain (assuming your system keychain has all of your apps signing certificates already in it)
2. Install Server 4.0 and Xcode 6.1. Apple has assured me that this is fixed in this version, though I have not tested this without also doing the above step. Additional information is available on the Apple forums here:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1053902#1053902

Comment: thanks for your answer! How to "override the xcode keychain"?

Comment: This method is described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639398/xcode-continuous-integration-provisioning-profile-error/26487466#26487466

Comment: Do I need to do this for Xcode 6.1 & X Server 4? Or this issue fixed in 6.1 version?

Comment: Strange, but the issue misteriously vanished!
Do yon know how to setup provisioning profiles on server correct?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue and I'm using Xcode 6.1 and Server 4.0. Does anyone have a solution or work around for this?

Comment: @MCFlakes I am also seeing this on XCode 6.1 and Server 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and to fix it, in the target scheme, I've changed the Build Configuration of "Run" and "Analyze" to "Release" and it worked!

My scheme has no target for test, but I have another target with test and it works fine with debug configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In your OS X Server account's Keychain Access app, select your certificate's Private Key and allow access by all applications.

`Get Info > Access Control > Allow all applications to access this item`

Source:
http://faq.sealedabstract.com/xcodeCI/#signing-for-distribution